# Create an clickable Icon next to a WordPress product attribute for more information

Tags: wordpress, button, woocommerce, attributes, label

I am trying to add a clickable icon like a "Information" icon next to a Product variation Attribute in wordpress (woocomerce). I was also hoping that this button or icon to would link to an anchor element further down the page.

For example the product attribute is "sizes" and the info button is next to the attribute label,
When that icon is clicked, user is hyperlinked to the section that contains the product sizes.

is this possible?

Thank you, any help with this would be appreciated.